# Prove that all roots of $\sum_{r=1}^{70} \frac{1}{x-r} =\frac{5}{4} $ are real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> **Prove that all roots of** $$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{70} \dfrac{1}{x-r} =\dfrac{5}{4} $$
>
> **are real**

I encountered this question in my weekly test. I tried setting $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{70} \dfrac{1}{x-r} = \dfrac{P'(x)}{P(x)} $ ; where $\displaystyle P(x) = \prod_{r=1}^{70} (x-r)$ and tried to use some inequality, but to no avail.

Can we also generalize this?

> **Find the condition such that**
>
> $$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{x-r} = a $$
>
> **has all real roots.**
>
> $n\in \mathbb{Z^+} \ ;  \ a\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alternatively: suppose that the function has a complex root; call it $x+iy$; $y\neq 0$.

Then $$\sum_{r=1}^{70}\frac{1}{x-r+iy}=\frac{5}{4}$$

multiply by the conjugate to get

$$\sum_{r=1}^{70}\frac{x-r-iy}{(x-r)^2+y^2}=\frac{5}{4}$$

which implies

$$\operatorname{Im}\left( \sum_{r=1}^{70}\frac{x-r-iy}{(x-r)^2+y^2} \right)=0$$
or
$$\sum_{r=1}^{70}\frac{-y}{(x-r)^2+y^2}=0$$
which is a contradiction since each term has the same sign and is nonzero.

Comment: One might mention that this is essentially the proof of the [Gauss-Lucas Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Lucas_theorem)

Comment: +1, but -- why do you structure it as a proof by contradiction? (If you remove the unnecessary assumption that $y \neq 0$, isn't it a perfectly valid direct proof that the imaginary part of any solution is 0?)

Comment: Good point. I guess my mind jumps to contradiction.

Answer (score 13):

Hint: Note that the derivative of the left-hand side, when it exists, is negative. So our function is decreasing in any interval $(k,k+1)$ where $1\le k\le 70-1$.

In this interval, our function is very large positive when $x$ is a tiny bit larger than $k$, and very large negative when $x$ is a tiny bit smaller than $k+1$. So by the Intermediate Value Theorem our equation has a root between $k$ and $k+1$.

Comment: This yields 69 real roots of the 70th degree polynomial but then the 70th  must also be real because the co-efficients are real so non-real roots occur in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @user254665: I had left that out to leave something to do. Another way of identifying the $70$-th is to use the same argument on $(70,\infty)$. Just to the right of $70$ the function is very large, and it decreases to $0$, passing $5/4$ along the way.

Comment: Ok. Good presentation.